# Is it good to summarize your study cases in a thesis?

Tags: thesis, writing

I am writing my thesis and it is a survey. I am making a classification of some algorithms in groups.

Will it be good to add a summarized version (max one page) of each article that contains one of the algorithms?

My prof wants me to make the thesis longer but I haven't encountered this approach before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very point of a survey work / literature review chapter / background section/related work section is to summarize the existing work that in other articles.

These sections are compulsory in my sub-field (NLP/ML). With all papers having a related work section, and all thesises having a literature review chapter.
More generally It is my understanding that even in fields that don't include a related work section in papers; they do include a literature review in thesises

The notion of one page max per summary, is I feel a bit constraining though.
For example in a book I recently wrote that summaries the state of my subfield, sometimes it took me 2-3 pages to summarize a particular complex or particularly important algorithm.
Conversely, other times I was able to summarize 5 algorithms in just 2 pages;
and I could highlight that infact they were all variants on the same overall principle (and highlighting these common features in works that are not obviously from the same source is a good thing to be doing.)